# How to set maximum total size for all Emacs backup files?

Tags: emacs, backup

Annoyed by the automatic backup files Emacs creates by default, yet acknowledging their potential utility, I set them to be saved to a hidden folder so I can forget about them until needed.

How can I set the maximum size for that folder, deleting the oldest backups as necessary?

Comment: For the file size check, see `backup-enable-predicate`:  its default value is the function `normal-backup-enable-predicate` which checks if it is a file in a temp directory and, if so, it returns `nil` - you can define an extended function to also return `nil` if the file size is bigger than your threshold  and change `backup-enable-predicate` to point to your extended function (for determining the size, see `file-attributes` and `file-attribute-size`).

Comment: For the directory size check, I don't think there is much help in emacs : it's probably easier to use bash or python to write a script that can run as a cron job.

Comment: Only one question per question post, please. I removed your question about setting the max backup file size - please post that separately.